# Name Mangling In Python Regarding Setter methods

Tags: python, setter, name-mangling

I had an issue with my setter methods not working when the if conditions were met, and I was not sure why (I ended up fixing it, but my question is WHY this fixed it). Here is my code:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, employee_id):
        self.__name = name
        self.__employee_id = employee_id 

    #Set property for name
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name.capitalize()
    
    #Set setter for name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        if name.isalpha():
            self.__name = name.capitalize()
        else:
            self.__name = 'Unknown'
           

    #Set property for employeeid
    @property
    def employee_id(self):
        return f"{self.__employee_id:0>4}"

    #Set setter for employeeid
    @employee_id.setter
    def employee_id(self, employee_id):
        if len(employee_id) == 0:
            self.__employee_id = '9999'
        else:
            self.__employee_id = employee_id
          

    #Str format to print out name 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{self.employee_id}>: {self.name}"
```

What I did to fix my issue was remove the __ from name and employee_id ONLY in the init method, and the if conditions in my setters worked (printed out "<9999>: Unknown", when it kept printing out "<0000>: " before).
Can anyone explain to me why this worked?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question would be clearer with a [mre] for both cases - working and not working - for each, a single block of code that can be copied, pasted and run.

Comment: Using for example `self.name = name` in `__init__` actually calls your setter when creating an employee.  Otherwise, the name isn't validated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you. In that case, are you only able to use double underscores in your init method if your class does not have any setter methods?

Comment: No, you just set the double underscore directly without validation. You can do it if that’s what you want, but in this case it wasn’t.